# ApolloError: this.cache.batch is not a function

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

trying some auth mutation over Apollo/client 3.4.1 and i have this error :

```
ApolloError: this.cache.batch is not a function
    at new ApolloError (/var/task/node_modules/@apollo/client/errors/errors.cjs.js:35:28)
    at Object.error (/var/task/node_modules/@apollo/client/core/core.cjs.js:1073:90)
    at notifySubscription (/var/task/node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:140:18)
    at onNotify (/var/task/node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:179:3)
    at SubscriptionObserver.error (/var/task/node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:240:7)
    at /var/task/node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/utilities.cjs.js:1015:40
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) {
  graphQLErrors: [],
  clientErrors: [],
  networkError: TypeError: this.cache.batch is not a function
      at QueryManager.refetchQueries (/var/task/node_modules/@apollo/client/core/core.cjs.js:1601:24)
      at QueryManager.markMutationResult (/var/task/node_modules/@apollo/client/core/core.cjs.js:1136:18)
      at /var/task/node_modules/@apollo/client/core/core.cjs.js:1043:49
      at both (/var/task/node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/utilities.cjs.js:1004:53)
      at /var/task/node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/utilities.cjs.js:997:72
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at Object.then (/var/task/node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/utilities.cjs.js:997:24)
      at Object.next (/var/task/node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/utilities.cjs.js:1005:49)
      at notifySubscription (/var/task/node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:135:18)
      at onNotify (/var/task/node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:179:3),
  extraInfo: undefined
}
```

Comment: i had to go back to apollo/client 3.3.21 to make it work again.

Comment: you might want to review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Molomby can you explain the problem ?

Answer (score 5):

This issue is related to the deprecated cacher class.

If you are using some cacher class just make sure it's up to date. Since Apollo v3 the InMemoryCacher class is provided by @apollo/client so make sure you are importing it from this package.

More on this issue,
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/8566
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/

Comment: ran into this while switching to @apollo/client, if doing this yourself, make sure you've got apollo-client uninstalled or it might use it instead. can also run into errors like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70089245/client-watchquery-cannot-be-called-with-fetchpolicy-set-to-standby-error-th